# Adding a cms plugin to a placeholder from code

Tags: python, django, plugins, placeholder, django-cms

I'm trying to add a plugin to a PlaceholderField from code.
I have a model (Question) with a few fields, one of them is a PlaceholderField.

What I want to do is adding a TextPugin (or any other generic cms_plugin) to that Placeholder Field. This is needed as I don't want people to add the TextPlugin manually from the frontend edit mode of the cms, but rather creating it myself so they can just add the right content after.

I know there's add_plugin from cms.api, but still I'd need to figure out a way to convert the PlaceholderField to Placeholder for it to work.

This is the code I have right now.

**models.py**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.db import models
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.cms_plugins import TextPlugin
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
from cms.api import add_plugin

class Question(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic')
    question = models.CharField(_("Question"),max_length=256)
    answer = PlaceholderField ('Answer plugin')
    priorityOrder = models.IntegerField(_("Priority Order"))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):        

        # Here's the critical point: I can cast self.answer to PlaceholderField, 
        # but I can't cast it to a Placeholder or add a placeholder to it

        add_plugin( ????, plugin_type='TextPlugin', language='us',)
        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # set the correct name of a django.model object in the admin site
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Topic title"),max_length=256)
    priorityOrder = models.IntegerField(_("Priority Order"))

    # set the correct name of a django.model object in the admin site
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Any help (including alternative ways of doing this) is really welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A `PlaceholderField` is nothing but a `ForeignKey` that auto-creates the relation to a new `Placeholder` object when a new instance is created.

As a result, you cannot use `add_plugin` on a `PlaceholderField` on an unsaved instance. You need to call `super().save()` *first*, then call `add_plugin(self.answer, ...)`.